# My send token response gives me an error message of "error": "option expires is invalid"

Tags: node.js, authentication

[This is the image of the function where the error lies, it is linked to the second image which is my sendTokenRespone Script[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z5vi.jpg)
[This is my send Token response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFJTY.jpg)

[This is the error message in my console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SpLA.jpg)

Comment: Well please add code and log.  Nobody has too much time see your images. explain little about your what you trying to archive.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I already figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Check your auth.js controller on line 107, as the message on your console window.
This has something to do with your .env file:
Not being accessed or probably your "JWT_EXPIRE" or "JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRE" variable names inside the config file are not the same as the ones inside your auth.js controller.
This should fix it.